# How to .Net Unit Tests with SQLite with Multiple Databases

Tags: .net, sqlite, unit-testing

My work has various .Net C# classes to perform discrete actions (i.e. get items in user's shopping cart, get list of products available, etc). I am looking to added unit tests to these classes/methods using Visual Studio unit test projects. My goal is to have the unit tests self contained where they do not depend on an external database. So I started investigating SQLite. I'm thinking each unit test will create it's own "mock" database to be used by the corresponding classes/methods that the unit test is executing.

Here is the problem I am running into. The real classes/methods execute SQL with fully qualified (guess that is the right term) database names and schemas as part of the query. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Database01.Schema01.Table01
```

In SQLite is there a way to make it work with these type of table references? I see there is an ATTACH command where you can attach multiple databases to one connection. Then you reference a table with *database-name.table-name*. That is still missing the middle schema part though. Any thoughts?

Comment: A unit test should not need a database at all. Show an example of a method you'd like to test in order to get advice on restructuring your code. Also hardcoding database names sounds like a badly maintainable idea. I guess it's too late in the project to switch to an ORM?

Answer (score 0):

If that code does *not* take care to quote database/schema names correctly, you could name the database `[Database01.Schema01]` and then tell that code that the database is called `[Database01`, and the schema, `Schema01]`.

If your code is too smart for that, or if the database/schema names are fixed, then there is nothing you can do with SQLite.